# I'm looking for a word that describes someone who sees themselves as a custodian of the land - working to do what is right rather than what is easy

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that describes someone who sees themselves as a custodian of the land - working to do what is right rather than what is easy

Comment: Hello, MRob. I assume you mean 'land' as in 'nation', as opposed to referencing the conservationist role? Superman rather than David Attenborough (though some confuse the two)?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELU. I see you've garnered a close vote, so I'll try to explain how to improve your question. For single word requests, you should include a sample sentence to show how you want to use the word (i.e. verb or noun) and words that you've considered but rejected and why you've rejected them. This helps to narrow down the answers.

Comment: @Pam There should be (2) a requirement that close-voters must explain their reason/s to newbies (ie no printed reason, no close-vote possible); (1) a requirement that newbies stick to the 'add reasonable research' (ie no reasonable research shown, the question doesn't materialise on ELU) requirement, to maintain standards. //Thanks for the explanation kindly given to OP. And don't ask me how to get (1) to work automatically. Please. // I'll check back tomorrow. No research added, my close-vote added.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I'd go further and require a printed reason for any down vote as well as any close vote (not just newbies - you can get a fair amount of rep but still make newbie mistakes!). However, even if you added that to the technology, chances are you'd get a bunch of comments simply saying "-1". Someone has to be the change they want to see in the world; it might as well be me!

Comment: In contrast to @EdwinAshworth, I immediately assumed the term being sought would apply to those who adhere to environmentally sound and sustainable land-use practices. If I am correct I have a word to suggest; but please, MRob, take note of these different ways of reading your question, and clarify your intention accordingly.

Comment: As my close vote is attracting complaints for lack of explanation - I close voted as "unclear what you're asking" as I don't think it's clear what you're asking. What do you mean by "custodian"? What do you mean by "land"? What do you mean by "what is right rather than what is easy"? Some examples are probably required.

Comment: This person is a committed crusader.

Comment: But the person asking the question does not seem very committed to the question.

Answer (score -2):

A good thesaurus would help you here. Some words synonymous with "custodian" though imply an *appointed position* - for example, "curator" or "steward".

If you are looking to imply that someone is acting as custodian out of moral duty, like a superhero, then perhaps the best alternatives would be:

- overseer
- protector
- defender
- saviour
- guardian